# Can I extends a sub class of Proxy class?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4

I want to create a complete (and real) 2-dimensional array.

In order to use a maximum of Adobe code, I want to use ListCollectionView which can manage sort and filters. But to use a second dimension, I need to override getProperty method, like following code.

package
{
    import flash.utils.flash_proxy;
    import mx.collections.ListCollectionView;

```
public class SubClass extends ListCollectionView /* extends Proxy */
{
    override flash_proxy function getProperty(name : *) : *
    {
        ...
    }
    override flash_proxy function setProperty(name : *, value : *) : void
    {
        ...
    }

}
```

}

This code doesn't work. Flash Builder 4 said to me:

```
1004      Namespace was not found or is not a compile-time constant.
```

If anyone has a solution or a clue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy :

```
use namespace flash_proxy;
```

Comment: Ah....but both the import and use of the namespace need to be *before* the class declaration...makes sense I guess given that the namespcae needs to be visible to declare the method.